# Analytic formula for leading eigenvector of $uu^T + vv^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, eigenvalues, svd

Let $u$ and $v$ be nonzero column vectors of size $n$ and consider the $n \times n$ positive-definite matrix $A:=uu^T + vv^T$. In this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112201/168758, the eigenvalues of $A$ were computed analytically.

## Question

I wonder whether there is an analytic formula for the eigenvectors of $A$.

## Observation

This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112197/87355 shows how to compute the eigenvalues of $A$ via 2 iterations of Gram-schmidt. The method also contains a blueprint for computing the eigenvectors, in principle. The issue is that this method gives an eigendecomposition in a basis $\mathcal B=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots\}$ which is different from the standard basis. With all of this in hand, how to get eigenvectors of $A$ in the standard basis efficiently (for example, without computing the other $n-2$ vectors $u_3,\ldots,u_n$ of the basis $\mathcal B$, and then doing a change of basis formula).

## Update

Fibonatic's answer along with the refs above, here is some python code which solves the problem (hope it helps someone else):

```
def special_eig(u, v, tol=1e-9):
    """
    Computes leading eigenvalue and eigenvector of uu^T + vv^T

    Notes
    =====
    Many of the computations can become numerically unstable. Most of the code
    is to overcome these potential issues.
    """
    from math import sqrt
    u2 = u.dot(u)
    v2 = v.dot(v)
    uv = u.dot(v)

    # check for linear dependence
    if u2 <= tol:
        return v2, v
    if v2 <= tol:
        return u2, u.copy()
    tmp = uv ** 2 / (u2 * v2)
    if abs(tmp - 1) <= tol:
        return u2 + v2, u.copy()

    # at this point, u and v are linear independent
    disc = sqrt((u2 - v2) ** 2 + 4 * (uv) ** 2)
    eigval = .5 * (u2 + v2 + disc)
    if abs(uv) <= tol:
        x = uv / (eigval - v ** 2)
    else:
        x = (eigval - u2) / uv
    eigvec = u + x * v
    return eigval, eigvec
```

Comment: I think you want to look at this question: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24399/eigenvalues-of-abt

Comment: The answer there only gives you bounds, but the eigenvalues can be computed exactly. I've written this up in Section 2.5 of this paper: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2018-newton-stokes.pdf The terms there are symmetric matrices and tensors of rank 4, but the same argument works in exactly the same way for the vectors and matrices you have.

Comment: I'm interested in the eigenvectors, not the eigenvalues. As stated in my question, the eigenvalues can be computed explictly (see refs in question).

Comment: Use the top answer in your linked question (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112197/11268), after a change of basis you have a 2x2 matrix whose eigenvalues *and* eigenvectors can be computed explicitly (because it is only 2x2; just substitute the closed-form eigenvalues into the characteristic equation and compute the null space by hand), then change the basis back.

Comment: @Krill Thanks for the input. As remarked in my question, my main issue is the "change of basis". I don't know how to do it without computing the full basis (not just $u_1$ and $u_2$, but an entire basis containing them). Or maybe I'm missing something ? Any detailed hnts around this will be extremely helpful.

Comment: You could do this "change of basis" by just using Gram-Schmidt, choosing for example $u$ as the first basis vector and project $v$ to the plane orthogonal to $u$. However, this does require calculating vectors, which might require significantly more memory and computation power compared to using just scalar equation as shown in my answer.

Comment: It's really not that difficult: The non-trivial eigenvalues all correspond to eigenvectors that are in the $u$-$v$ plane. In other words, all of the eigenvectors that correspond to non-zero eigenvalues are linear combinations of $u$ and $v$, and it should not be very difficult to compute them analytically.

Comment: Sure, that's precisely how fibonatic's answer below goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can start by writing the eigenvalue problem

$$
\left(A - \lambda_i\,I\right) w_i = 0, \tag{1}
$$

with $\lambda_i$ one of the two eigenvalues and $w_i$ its eigenvector. By using the definition of $A$ $(1)$ can also be written as

$$
\langle u, w_i\rangle u + \langle v, w_i\rangle v = \lambda_i\,w_i. \tag{2}
$$

This implies that $w_i$ has to be a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, so $w_i = \alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v$. Plugging this into $(2)$ yields

$$
\langle u, \alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v\rangle u + \langle v, \alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v\rangle v = \lambda_i (\alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v). \tag{3}
$$

In the case that $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent (so $v = x\,u$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$) the matrix can also be written as $A = (1+x^2) u\,u^\top$. This means that it has only one non-zero eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector would just be $u$.

In the case that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent $(3)$ can be factored into the following two scalar equation which are multiplied by $u$ and $v$ respectively

$$
\langle u, \alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v\rangle = \lambda_i\,\alpha_i, \tag{4a}
$$ $$
\langle v, \alpha_i\,u + \beta_i\,v\rangle = \lambda_i\,\beta_i, \tag{4b}
$$

which should be equivalent equations, because $|w_i|$ should remain undetermined. For example when defining $x_i = \beta_i/\alpha_i$ it can be solved for using $(4a)$ and $(4b)$ respectively

$$
x_i = \frac{\lambda_i - |u|^2}{\langle u,v\rangle}, \tag{5a}
$$ $$
x_i = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\lambda_i - |v|^2}. \tag{5b}
$$

Choosing $\alpha_i=1$ gives $w_i = u + x_i\,v$ (one could normalize $w_i$ if desired). In the case that $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ $(5a)$ is not well defined and similarly for $(5b)$ when $\lambda_i = |v|^2$. However, in both cases $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $A$, since if $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ then $A\,v = |v|^2 v$ and $A\,u = |u|^2 u$.

It can be shown that $\lambda_i=u^2$, $\lambda_j=v^2$ ($i\neq j$) and $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ are all equivalent. For this I assume that $|u|^2 \geq |v|^2$ (if this is not the case one could always swap the definitions of $u$ and $v$) in which case there should always exist a $x\geq0$ such that

$$
\sqrt{(|u|^2 - |v|^2)^2 + 4 \langle u,v\rangle^2} = \pm (|u|^2 - |v|^2 + 2\,x),
$$

with $x=0$ only when $\langle u,v\rangle=0$. Substituting this into the equation for the eigenvalues yields

$$
\lambda_i = \frac{|u|^2 - |v|^2 \pm (|u|^2 - |v|^2 + 2\,x)}{2},
$$

which can be simplified to $\lambda_1 = |u|^2 + x$ and $\lambda_2 = |v|^2 - x$. However, since $|u|^2 \geq |v|^2$ and $x\geq0$ implies that $|u|^2$ can only be an eigenvalue if $x=0$ and thus $|v|^2$ has to be an eigenvalue as well and $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ and vice versa.

One side note, namely this does demonstrate an analytical solution for the eigenvectors, but it might not always yield accurate results when implementing this directly numerically. For example when $\lambda_i$ is very close to but not exactly equal to $|u|^2$ or $|v|^2$ in $(5a)$ and $(5b)$ respectively, then one could lose quite some numerical accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Possible tyos in  (5a) and (5b) ? The same $x_i$ seems to be given by two inconsitent equations.

Comment: @dohmatob $(5a)$ and $(5b)$ should give the same answer, similar to how there is also [another way of writing the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Muller's_method) to a quadratic equation.

Comment: @dohmatob Their equivalence can also be shown by substituting in the solution for $\lambda_i$ and equating the right hand sides of $(5a)$ and $(5b)$, and multiplying both sides by their denominators.

Comment: ok, sure. I didn't yet work through the computations but the two formulae looked inconsistent from afar. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you say "[...] if $\lambda_i=\|v\|^2$ then both $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $A$" ?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that if $\|v\|^2$ is eigenvalue, then because $A$ has rank at most $2$ and trace $\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$, then $\|u\|^2$ is also an eigenvalue. Moreover, in this case one can prove that $u^Tv=0$ must hold, and so both $u$ and $v$ must be eigenvectors of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\|u\|^2$ and $\|v\|^2$ respectively.

Comment: In other words, for your (5a) and (5b) to be well-defined, it is sufficient to have $u^Tv \ne 0$.

Comment: @dohmatob I have added a section do my answer which expands on this equivalence, so hopefully this would make it more clear. (Though you have already shown this with calculations yourself, however it might make it clearer to others who might read this answer as well.)

Comment: Great. BTW, there is a follow up question here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33623/16807